# mySql search using LIKE operator and partial search

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have the following code:

```
$search_str= "I want to be a programmer.";
```

And I have the following data in mysql database.

```
I want to be.
```

I have used: `LIKE %$search_str%`
But it return no data.

If I search with only " I want" then getting the result.
I want to get the data if any part OR full part is matched.

Comment: You need to show us the full code & query you are using to do this.

Comment: $search_text="anything";
$query="SELECT * from tbl_questions where question LIKE '%$search_text%' ";

Comment: That's your entire code??? If that's the case is it any wonder its not working... Please post the *full code and query* you are using.

Comment: You're misunderstanding how like works. The percent sign is a wildcard. So it will match the text in between exactly, plus anything in front or behind the text. So when your like term has more characters than the table field, it won't match. The only way to achieve what you want is to break the sentence into individual words and do like statements connected by "or"

Comment: Disregard my last sentence. I didn't think that through well enough.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to do the like the other way around and say where your input is like the column.

```
SELECT *
FROM <TABLE>
WHERE <input> LIKE CONCAT('%', <TABLENAME>.<COLUMNNAME>, '%')
```

Comment: Can this be parameterized?

Answer (score 0):

To get the results according to your criteria you can add additional like clause in reverse way to match column against your string

```
select *
from table
where search_column like '%I want to be a programmer.%'
or 'I want to be a programmer.' like concat('%',search_column ,'%')
```